# Angular 7: assigning object value returned from observable to variable

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend, angular-httpclient

I have a problem when im trying to assign return value from service to component.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getInspectionData();
  }

  getInspectionData() {
    this.auctionService.getInspectionResult(`df570718-018a-47d8-97a2-f943a9786536`)
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(`this is data returned: `, data);
      }, error => {
        console.log('failed to get data', error);
      }, () => {
        console.log('getInspectionResult successfully processed');
      });
  }
```

It successfuly got returned value in console.log

[console.log result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QGHK.png)

inside the *`subscribe()`*. there are seems like no problem. even i set the console.log to variable inside the *`subscribe()`*:

```
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.inspectionResult = data;
    console.log(`value from getInspectionData: `, this.inspectionResult);
```

**it had give the `this.inspectionResult` output correctly.**

it should be correct, right? and then i add `this.inspectionResult = data;`

but....

when i test it, the variable gets wrong and it gets ***`'{}'`***. the code below:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getInspectionData();
    console.log(`value from getInspectionData: `, this.inspectionResult);
  }

  getInspectionData() {
    this.auctionService.getInspectionResult(`df570718-018a-47d8-97a2-f943a9786536`)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.inspectionResult = data;
      }, error => {
        console.log('failed to get data', error);
      }, () => {
        console.log('getInspectionResult successfully processed');
      });
  }
```

[this is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCHJP.png)

by the way, i had assigned the variable like this:

```
  inspectionResult: InspectionResult = <InspectionResult>{};
  inspectionResultData: InspectionResultData = <InspectionResultData>{};
```

**my question is:**

1. Why the data value doesnt assign to the `this.inspectionResult` ?
2. Why the ngOnInit() doesnt give the output way i expecting? (the `console.log()` in `ngOnInit()` should run after the `getInspectionData();` )

Comment: because  .subscribe  is an asynchronous call.If you want the variable to fill value,then use settimeout

Comment: You are printing `this.inspectionResult` before the call gets the data from `getInspectionData`., that's why you get `{} value. You should return wait for the value to be back from service before using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that may due to

this.getInspectionData();
console.log(`value from getInspectionData:`, this.inspectionResult);

in this case there may delay in this.getInspectionData() this process.
but console.log() is exicuting before the above method complete.

you must await for method complete. please refere this you will get some clarity

http://www.damirscorner.com/blog/posts/20170127-Angular2TutorialWithAsyncAndAwait.html

Comment: thanks! i also found that i need to resolve the first one with resolver. i was trying to get 2 API concurrently with the 2nd API dependent to the first one.